# Powershell to match the current line and next line then out-file

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I'm trying to extract the data whereby:

line 1 = Report ID + Line 2 = "Machine no" + Line 3 = OFFLINE

Then `Out-File` to a new file.

Sample data

```
Report ID           page1

Machine no  1234    

        OTHERS
            12
        offline
            12
        OTHERS
            23
        offline
            37
        OTHERS
            89
        offline
            65
```

The result I'm looking for look something like the below after processing:

```
Report ID           page 4

    Machine no  1234    
        offline
            12
        offline
            37
        offline
            65
```

Comment: In StackOverflow the general expectation is that you've at least tried to do it yourself first, and then come here with the exact problem you have.

Comment: Your question is quite vague and contains no actual code so we don't know what, or how, you are trying to do. (Always include your code even if it doesn't work!). I would recommend reading [ask] and the [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). These will help you figure out what your question is missing so you can update it and get an answer that will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Select-String` cmdlet with the `-Context` Parameter to search through a file and then select how many lines of contextual info you want to get back from your search.

For instance, if we take your input file and store it in a variable called `$input` like so:

```
$inputFile= Get-Content C:\Path\To\YourFile.txt
$inputFile| Select-string 'machine no'
>Machine no  1234
```

We can then find matches for the phrase 'offline' with this:

```
$inputFile| Select-String offline -Context 0,1
```

This states that I want you to search for the word 'offline' and give me zero lines proceeding it, and one line after it, giving us this output:

```
>         offline
              12
>         offline
              37
>         offline
              65
```

We can put this all together to build this and generate a new output file that would look like this.

```
$out= ''
$out += $inputFile| Select-string 'machine no'
$out += "`n"
$out += $inputFile| Select-String offline -Context 0,1 | ForEach-Object {$_.Context.DisplayPostContext}

#Resulting file would look this, just the name of the machine and then the number of each offline...uh, whatever it is.
    Machine no  1234    
        12             37             65
```

If I were you, I'd adapt this flow to make PowerShell objects and properties instead, like this:

```
$Report = [pscustomobject]@{ID='';MachineNo='';OfflineMembers=@()}
$Report.ID = ($inputFile | select-string page -Context 0 ).ToString().Split('page')[-1]
$Report.MachineNo = ($inputFile | Select-string 'machine no').ToString().Trim().Split()[-1]
$Report.OfflineMembers = $inputFile | Select-String offline -Context 0,1 | ForEach-Object {
            [pscustomobject]@{Value='Offline';ID=$_.Context.DisplayPostContext.Trim()}
            }

>$Report

ID MachineNo OfflineMembers                                                             
-- --------- --------------                                                             
1 1234      {@{Value=Offline; ID=12}, @{Value=Offline; ID=37}, @{Value=Offline; ID=65}}
 $Report.OfflineMembers
Value   ID
-----   --
Offline 12
Offline 37
Offline 65
```